# Informatica repository switch

Tags: repository, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are in a situation where the server that host the repository blew up for our test instance.

Our DBA was able to restorethe Prod version of the repository. However, I am learning now that on the INFA service account is different between the two systems; INFA on PROD and INFA_B on Test.

So the informatica services are not coming back up. I have tried infasetup UpdateGatewayNode to correct one. However catalina log still shows the mismatch between "Domain name [test] from the node configuration file does not match the domain name [prod] in the domain configuration repository."

Since the informatica admin console is not up, I am querying the repository tables and manually updating the prod values to test. I noticed the update on repository table "po_DOMAINSERVICECONFIG" is giving a new error "Caught an exception in one of the PCSF or PCSF base servlet threads"

I am posting this question hoping that someone else may have had similar issues in the past that could provide some insight.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hello 
In this case check the host file in which the host name of the database is to be provided with domain name.
Check C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host
If there is no host name, please add it and your issue will be reslolved

Comment: Thanks, Jim. Sorry forgot to mention that we are on a Linux box. I have checked the /etc/hosts file and verified the domain name exist in the file. Furthermore, I have also tried to backup/restore domain from prod to dev. I believe the restoring part is working fine as all the domain db objects get copied over to the schema. However the updategatewaynode is not working correctly even though I get a success message. No services are coming back up yet.